# Interference between "where's" Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to load more users when roll scroll, but the orWhere of lastname is causing interference, if I remove the orWhere, works fine, return the next users...

```
public function users_more($last_id) {
    $users = User::where('name', 'like', '%' . $_POST['search_data'] . '%')
            ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%' . $_POST['search_data'] . '%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('id', '<', $last_id)
            ->with(['userProfile' => function($query) {
                    $query->select('count_followers', 'user_id');
            }])->orderBy('name', 'desc')
            ->take(6)
            ->get();

    return view("site.list.header.search.usersmore", compact('users'));
}
```

Users showed:

```
10
9
8
7
```

Next showed:

```
10
9
8
7
```

Should show:

```
6
5
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
User::where(function($q) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $_POST['search_data'] . '%')
          ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%' . $_POST['search_data'] . '%');
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->where('id', '<', $last_id)
    ->with(['userProfile' => function($query) {
            $query->select('count_followers', 'user_id');
    }])
    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
```